# General chain rule help/ derivatives help.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've been thinking too much about the chain rule and I've got myself in a muddle:

> Suppose $y=f(g(x))$, we can easily show that $\frac {dy}{dx} =
>  f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. I would ask please that someone write out
>   $f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ in '$\frac d{dx}$' notation. I'm actually not
>   quite sure what I can't get my head around, I think I'm struggling
>   with the difference between, say $\frac {df}{dg}$ and $\frac
> {df}{dg(x)}$ if there is one and similarly things like $\frac
> {df}{dx}$ and $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}$.

Despite what it may seem like from this question, I am familiar with partial derivatives, so feel free to use those in your answers.

I don't know what's going on in my head today, this is a little embarrassing, so apologies for the stupid question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not very rigourous, but the notation speaks for itself:
$$\frac{\mathrm d\bigl(f(g(x))\bigr)}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}=\frac{\mathrm d\bigl(f(g(x))\bigr)}{\mathrm d(g(x))}\times\frac{\mathrm d(g(x))}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}.$$

A concrete example:
\begin{align*}\frac{\mathrm d\bigl(\sin\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigr)}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}&=\frac{\mathrm d\sin\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\mathrm d\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigr)}
\times \frac{\mathrm d\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigr)}{\mathrm d(x^2+1)}\times\frac{\mathrm d(x^2+1)}{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}\\
&=\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigr)\times\frac1{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\times 2x=\frac{x\cos\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigr)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, is this different to $\frac{df}{dg}$ x $\frac {dg}{dx}$?

Comment: @user307463 that should be $\frac{d(f \circ g)}{dg}$ for your first term.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand this and you should feel lucky that you haven't touch on calculating derivative of an inverse function.

if $y=f(g(x))$, you can write it in two equations.

$$y=f(u)$$
$$u=g(x)$$

Then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{df(u)}{du}\frac{dg}{dx}$$

After that, replace u with g(x) for the first term.